# How do I swipe a UIScrollView left or right using Frank?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, cucumber, frank

I am starting to use frank-cucumber to test an iOS app.  I have a paging `UIScrollView` and I want to test a swipe to the right and left.  I would like to do something like this: `Then swipe scrollview to the right` or `Then page once to the right`.  Is there code in place to let me do this?

Thanks for the answers.